# Bitcoin-core not saving transaction data

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I have installed Bitcoin Core for full node and the synchronization seems to have finished, but there seems to be no transaction data saved on my PC storage. Why is this? Hopefully it should be several hundred gigs, right?

PC environment is Ubuntu.
The green check mark is still there in the lower right corner. The node also appears to be working. But there is no historical data?

Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: It's possible your node is running in "pruned" mode, where block data is downloaded and validated, but later discarded after validation, and only the chainstate is kept in order to be able to verify future blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How do I set it to normal mode?

Comment: Pruning can be turned off in the "settings" menu under "options", "main"

Comment: Resolved. I appreciate.